# Find the smallest distance between the profiles

Tags: r

I would like to find the smallest distance between the profiles stored in a data frame. I am interested especially in one row in comparison to the rest of the rows stored in the data frame.

That's a data frame:

```
structure(list(`10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `34` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 393090, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6718400, 
                                                                      0, 311350, 0), `59` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2164949.7, 
                                                                                              4834137.6, 0, 0, 0, 1187816.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1340912.5, 0
                                                                      ), `84` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8607100, 0, 0, 17586713.2, 
                                                                                  22629743.6, 0, 0, 0, 2808791.7, 0, 0, 4026222.5, 0, 0, 0, 1981900, 
                                                                                  0), `110` = c(2296000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2140221.7, 0, 0, 5809230.6, 
                                                                                                0, 0, 37134898.5, 3861828.7, 2553100, 0, 12075845.8, 0, 0, 1272950, 
                                                                                                8695273, 0, 0, 2657180, 2710080, 0), `134` = c(0, 0, 0, 1176150, 
                                                                                                                                               0, 1329596.7, 1471000, 0, 6511934, 6511934, 0, 18709227.3, 0, 
                                                                                                                                               1041211.2, 0, 6544176.9, 0, 0, 2412651.7, 7724956.9, 2878418.3, 
                                                                                                                                               0, 8620131.7, 2386972.8, 0), `165` = c(0, 1226610, 0, 1345098.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      2083771.9, 0, 1808231.4, 0, 0, 10742997.7, 0, 13060798.9, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      538340, 538340, 2791649.5, 0, 0, 6217622, 1316097.1, 4716931.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      0, 6615816.9, 1510532, 0), `199` = c(0, 1571525, 0, 1903038.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           1676700, 0, 888832.2, 0, 0, 9084418.6, 0, 11189460.1, 0, 0, 1807662.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           2564275, 0, 0, 18080359.7, 0, 0, 0, 2397710.2, 1717949.2, 0), 
               `234` = c(0, 1314900, 2482696, 1325684, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7321432.7, 
                         0, 9843409.2, 0, 0, 1073341.7, 2762775, 0, 0, 9335312.8, 
                         0, 0, 0, 1950788.2, 1509100, 0), `257` = c(0, 1568700, 14604298.7, 
                                                                    940162.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4779505.9, 0, 9691692.4, 0, 0, 735290, 
                                                                    2650165, 0, 2311383.7, 5193383.4, 0, 0, 0, 1341998.7, 1225325.6, 
                                                                    0), `362` = c(0, 0, 4190740.5, 288800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4846634.8, 
                                                                                  0, 9574498.7, 0, 0, 0, 1425600, 0, 8339312.1, 3877892.5, 
                                                                                  0, 0, 0, 1752866.7, 0, 0), `433` = c(0, 0, 773280, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                       0, 0, 0, 0, 3926582.8, 3926582.8, 5962586.5, 0, 0, 0, 1041400, 
                                                                                                                       0, 1972909.3, 1895439.4, 0, 0, 0, 963891.2, 0, 1109800), 
               `506` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9332272, 0, 0, 0, 
                         0, 0, 0, 2219100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `581` = c(0, 0, 0, 
                                                                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4371537.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2428800, 
                                                                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `652` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                           0, 1689871.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 988399.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                           0, 0), `733` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1250100, 0, 0, 1754205.3, 
                                                                                                                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `818` = c(0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 517340, 0, 0, 1149227.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `896` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 579846.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 0, 985931.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
               `972` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 858255.5, 0, 0, 0, 
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1039` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 848993.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                      0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("10", "34", "59", "84", "110", "134", 
                                                                                               "165", "199", "234", "257", "362", "433", "506", "581", "652", 
                                                                                               "733", "818", "896", "972", "1039"), row.names = c("Mark_1", 
                                                                                                                                                  "Mark_2", "Alex_1", "Katrin_1", "Georg_1", "Martin_1", 
                                                                                                                                                  "Tim_1", "Tom_1", "Mike_1", "Mike_2", "Mike_3", 
                                                                                                                                                  "Hare_1", "Dea_1", "Monty_1", "Monty_2", "Niko_1", 
                                                                                                                                                  "Lee_1", "Marq_1", "Otto_1", "Priaq_1", "Surkta_1", 
                                                                                                                                                  "Norsa_1", "Norsa_2", "Quer_1", "Quer_2"), class = "data.frame")
```

So the row named `Katrin_1` is the one which is interesting for me. I would like to find which rows have the smallest euclidean distance to `Katrin_1`. Let say 3-5 rows.

Comment: It looks we both are right! +1

Comment: Have you considered using `heatmap` to construct a dendrogram? That will cluster rows by distance.

Comment: what are the columns in your data frame?

Comment: I tried with dist but than the problem starts... My data frame is 100x bigger than the presented one. I am not sure how to find the smallest distances. Looking manually is impossible. I tried to use `min` function after the distance calculation but it doesn't give me the row name. Only the value for a distance and I would like to find not only one row but let's say 3-5 rows with the shortest distance.

Comment: `as.matrix(dist(df))[, "Katrin_1"]` will give you all the distances (with associated names) from this obs. Then you can `sort` it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's get rid of `Katrin_1` column with `df[!rownames(df) %in% "Katrin_1", ]`, subtract `df["Katrin_1", ]` from each of the remaining rows with `sweep`, find Euclidean distances by squaring the resulting matrix element-wise and using `rowSums`, use `which.min` to get the final result:

```
names(which.min(rowSums(sweep(df[!rownames(df) %in% "Katrin_1", ], 2, as.numeric(df["Katrin_1", ]), `-`)^2)))
# [1] "Mark_2"
```

This should be much more efficient than using `dist` as `dist` would compute all possible distances, while we need need only a few.